# Filter some lines from a textfile in python

Tags: python, file

I am currently creating a list from an input file like this:

```
list = inputFile.read().splitlines()
```

Then after that manually iterating through and making a second list of the items/lines I care about (which are lines 2,6,10,14,18...). Is there a faster way to do this just with `splitlines()` so automatically, `list` contains only the lines I care about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is the tool for the job:

```
from itertools import islice

for line in islice(inputFile, 2, None, 4):
    print line
```

Comment: As a note, `line` will include the newlines of the file, while the original method will *not*.

Comment: Line numbers usually count from 1, so `islice(inputFile, 1, None, 4)`  might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The more pythonic way is that don't read all the lines at once. You can use `enumerate` to iterate over your file object and keep the expected lines :

```
with open(file_name) as f:
  list_of lines=[line for index,line in enumerate(f) if index in set_of_indices]
```

Note that here its better to put your line numbers in a `set` object which   its membership checking order is O(1).

As mentioned in comment if you have a huge set of indices as a more optimized way in terms of memory use you can use a generator to preserve your lines, instead of a list comprehension  :

```
with open(file_name) as f:
  list_of lines=(line for index,line in enumerate(f) if index in set_of_indices)
```

Comment: This is good advice but the `itertools.islice` way is the better bet.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Yep this approach is a better choice for unordered indices.

Comment: This can be a problem for memory so a generator approach is better

Comment: Actually, you are fine, I forgot that enumerate is a generator :P

Comment: You should keep the list and add in an `iter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` also

```
f = inputFile.read()
to_read = [ 2,6,10,14,18]
for i,j in enumerate(f, 1):
    if i in to_read
        #your code here
```

Enumerate is a built in Python function to give an index to each object in an iterable.

```
>>> l = iter(["a", "b", "c"])
>>> [x for x in enumerate(l)]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: I think he wants every fourth line though. And it is good to tell exactly what `enumerate` is

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this if you want to read in the whole file.

```
readfile = file.read()
for x in range(2,len(readfile.split("\n"),4)):

    line = readfile[x]
    #Do stuff with x
```

Running through the file line by line instead of reading it in is better for memory.

```
count = 1
for line in file:
    if count <= 2:
        continue
    if count % 4 != 2 or (count % 4 == 0 and count <= 4):
        continue
        count += 1
    count += 1
    #Work with line
```